# Can you use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express to manage a Google Cloud SQL database instance?

Tags: sql-server, database, cloud, google-cloud-sql

My organisation is looking to create a cloud database which can be queried by customers and managed/accessed by 5-6 people within the organisation, to supercede an old rusty access database.

Currently we are familiar with the environment of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express and have transferred most of our information into a local SQL Server.

Having researched cloud server options online, Amazon RDS for SQL Server seemed to be a good contender but Google Cloud SQL Server seems cheaper for a database of our (really rather small) database.

The question is: can we still use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express to administer and update our database on Google Cloud?  Apparently Google Cloud works like MySQL, which is different from the SQL Server as Microsoft uses as I understand it?

Any insights/experiences much appreciated!

Comment: Dang I didn't know that. Thought Mr. Softie might be more keen on Azure. You sure? But if you use the Google Compute Engine like ec2, sure

Comment: No you cannot. The only database you can manage through SQL Server Management Studio are the various versions of SQL Server. Go carts have engines and move around but I would not use them for even short commutes to work. You will encounter all kinds of limitations when using Google Cloud and you will eventually realize you get what you pay for.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  What server might you suggest we use?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud SQL offers MySQL database only. Microsoft SQL server management tools will not work with it. If you're tied to SQL server, [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) might be a better option.